# Android: Eclipse does not show file

Tags: java, android, itext

I am creating a sub-folder named xml under the res folder in one of my projects. In the xml sub-folder I am creating an xml file, but this file does not show when I double-click the xml sub-folder under project explorer.

Comment: try refreshing the project by pressing F5 when the project selected

Comment: if you created the file outside of Eclipse, you need to refresh your Package Explore (F5) or right click/Refresh.

Comment: If you try to open the xml file (Ctrl+Shift+r and then type the name), can you see it? have you tried with the Package Explorer?

Answer (score 3):

It is a kind of common bugs in Eclipse.

Try these things in order:

```
1. right click subfolder Xml> Refresh.   
2. right click Res > Refresh.  
3. File > Refresh.
```

& if these dont work

```
4. Restart eciplse
```